# my add function chage in counter value but it's not reflecting on ui , when calling it from index view button add why ? angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

**FirstController.js**

```
function FirstController($scope) { 
 $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.add = function (amount) {
            $scope.counter += amount;
        }
    });}
```

**its view **Addtion.html****

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <h4>The simplest add</h4>
    <button ng-click="add(1)" class="button">Add</button>

    <h4>Current count: {{ counter }}</h4>
</div>
```

**its working when calling from this above view**

**button link on index view outside the this view is following**

Index view **Index.html**

```
<button ng-controller="FirstController" ng-click=" add(1);">Add</button>
```

this above button is on main view.. its change in counter is not reflecting in ui why??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the same controller on different elements to refer to the same object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453216/using-the-same-controller-on-different-elements-to-refer-to-the-same-object)

Comment: A side issue here is 

$scope.$apply(

usage from inside a controller, ALthough this may be just a PoC only, this shall not be done , only place where ever ever scope.$apply may be called shall be your directives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you declare `ng-controller` it creates a new scope. They are effectively separate instances of the same controller type.

If you want them to share a counter you could use the `$rootScope`, a shared service or emit/broadcast events, for example.

You can read more here: [Using the same controller on different elements to refer to the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453216/using-the-same-controller-on-different-elements-to-refer-to-the-same-object)